# Python 3.6 - image scraping with google-image-download

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I want to crawl some images for my `machine learning` practice and found this [google-image-download](https://github.com/hardikvasa/google-images-download) to very useful and the codes works out of the box.

However, at the moment, it only allow not more than 100 images, which is the limit from google image page(that only load 100 images per page).

The document said if you are using `pip install google_images_download`(which in my case, I am doing that), it will download together with `selenium` and by using `chromedriver`, you can download more than that limit.

however, everytime I run the code `python gimages.py`:

```
from google_images_download import google_images_download  

response = google_images_download.googleimagesdownload() 

arguments = {"keywords":"number plates","limit":200,"print_urls":True}  
paths = response.download(arguments)
print(paths)
```

I will get error:

> Looks like we cannot locate the path the 'chromedriver' (use the
>   '--chromedriver' argument to specify the path to the executable.) or
>   google chrome browser is not installed on your machine (exception:
>   expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType)

as I checked my installation, `selenium` already installed:
[image]

2. reading further, it said I can download `chromedriver` and put inside the same folder and call `python gimages.py --chromedriver "chromedriver"`, I still get the same error.

How can I resolve this?

I am using `conda` with `python 3.6`, running the `terminal` from conda. the code is already working, just that `chromedriver` part is not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the path... `"chromedriver"` is not a path...

You might need to the explicit path `"/path/to/chromedriver/folder"`.

In your case: `python gimages.py --chromedriver "/path/to/chromedriver/folder"`

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Sorry but I am using mac, and the `chromedriver` is `unix executable`. do I need to add extension?

Comment: Not working. I tried `"/path/to/folder"` and `"path/to/folder/"`. Both not working.

Comment: @sooon the example: `"/path/to/folder"` is just an example... you need to specify the path to the `chromedriver`...